# react updating state of one object changing the other object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

In my component two objects are based on this one json file. But when I try to change a value in one object the other object just updates automatically. How can I just change value of a field in one object and not the other. My code is

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import quest from './questions.json';

class Quest extends Component {

    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            questions: quest,
            keyquest: quest
        }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.changequest(this.state.questions);
    }

    changequest(quests){
        quests.map((data) => {
            data.answer = 'changed value';
        })
        this.setState({questions: quests});
    }

    render() {
        console.log(this.state.questions[0].answer);
        console.log(this.state.keyquest[0].answer);
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Test</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default Quest;
```

the out put of the two console.log statements is the same 'changed value'. What I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try stringify-ing quest in your state and parsing it back in changeQuest method, that way you are not mutating the same object.

```
this.state = {
      questions: JSON.stringify(quest),
      keyquest: JSON.stringify(quest)
    };
```

```
changequest(quests) {
    const q = JSON.parse(quests);
    this.setState({
      questions: q.map(data => {
        data.answer = "changed value";
        return data;
      })
    });
  }
```